# Increment the value of one column basing on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

How to generate the bus_day_mtd column from the Above picture, It should be automatically icremented based on the bus_day_flag= 1 and if bus_day_flag= 0, it should stay same

Comment: Which RDBMS? What have you tried till now?

Comment: please provide your sample data as a copyable text and not as an image. Best would be a [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: If you are making these insertions from client code, you could keep track of the current value of bus_day_mtd in a var named last_bus_day_mtd and, if the bus_day_flag you are about to insert is 1, inc last_bus_day_mtd prior to calling INSERT. And BTW, the picture is above, not below.

Comment: Please add the version number always. Some solutions are heavily depending on this (Like using `LAG()` or `SUM OVER`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update T
set bus_day_mtd = (
    select sum(bus_day) from T t2 where t2.ymd <= T.ymd
    --or cast(bus_day_flag as int) if referencing the bit column
)
```

Are you wanting this to calculate on the fly instead of in a static column?

Comment: Thanks @shawnt00 , This works

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do this with a cumulative sum:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             sum(case when bus_day_flag = 1 then bus_day end) over (order by ymd) as new_bus_day_mtd
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set bus_day_mtd = new_bus_day_mtd;
```